# How to document type parameters in the method or property with return type of generic Action or Func

Tags: .net, generics, type-parameter, xml-documentation

I have a very simple question, how would you document with xmldoc a method or a property with return type of generic Action or Func.
For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the print method. Parameters: file, printer name???
/// </summary> 
/// <value>
/// The print method.
/// </value>
public Action<string, string> PrintMethod { get; set; }
```

Which is the best practices in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to document the parameters of this action, don't use `Action<string, string>`: create a custom delegate instead, and document the parameters of the delegate.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the print method.
/// </summary> 
/// <value>
/// The print method.
/// </value>
public FilePrintAction PrintMethod { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Represents a method for printing a file to a printer
/// </summary> 
/// <parameter name="file">Path of the file to print</parameter>
/// <parameter name="printerName">Name of the printer</parameter>
public delegate void FilePrintAction(string file, string printerName);
```

Comment: This is a good advice! But the question is not whether to use an Action or Func as return type of a property or a method, but how to document it.

Comment: @Shurup, my point is that there is no "clean" way of documenting the parameters of an Action or Func; if you need to do that, create a specific delegate on which you can document the parameters.